# WordPress site url issues when using local docker container

Tags: docker

I have ported my wordpress site locally into Docker container, the home page is working fine, here is my folder structure

```
/
 -docker-compose.yml
 -src (I have copied my wordpress code from production to this folder)
 -db (It contains the db dump file)
```

My docker-compose.yml file is like this

```
version: '2'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress_wp
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: mypw
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html

  mysql:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypw
    volumes:
      - ./db/my_wp.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/my_wp.sql
```

Then I ran the command `docker-compose up` and site is accessible at `http://localhost:8080/`

but the issue is when I click on some menu, it redirects me to my production site i.e. `http://my-production-site/contact-us`

How can I fix the urls automatically?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though either your theme is using absolute URLs or you haven't changed the WordPress "site URL" to be localhost, hence it redirecting you to the production site upon clicking any menus.

A couple of options here:

- change your links within your theme to be relative
- modify your site URL within WordPress to be localhost